# AngularJS: Unable to access scope from within directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

`model.data` contains the following:

```
{
    "name": "Jamie",
    "age": 25
}
```

I have a directive that looks like:

```
<my-directive data="model.data"></my-directive>
```

I have defined the directive as follows:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){  
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'grid.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log($scope);
            console.log($scope.data);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that `console.log($scope)` returns the value in $scope. I can see it containing data:

```
{
    $$asyncQueue: Array[0],
    $$childHead: null,
    ...
    ...
    data: Array[1]
}
```

However, `console.log($scope.data)` returns `undefined`. Any clue why?

Comment: Seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3e27N/

Comment: Can you share how is `model.data` created

Comment: @ArunPJohny The output of `console.log($scope) can be found at http://i.imgur.com/9wBJU5N.png

Comment: As for creation of model.data, it belongs to a different controller. `model.data` is having the values for certain. In the page containing the directive, if I display the value of `{{model.data}}`, then I can see it correctly.

Comment: The best part is that in the templateUrl, if I also attempt to display `{{model.data}}`, then its value can be seen. But I can't seem to access it only from the controller.

Comment: can you change the fiddle to recreate the case

Comment: @ArunPJohny Nope. I can't reproduce this in the fiddle, when in fact, I am doing exactly the same. Anyhow, this is how I am getting my model in the Main Page Controller (different from the controller used by the directive): `$http.get('data/everything.json').success(function(data) {  
    $scope.model = data;  
});`

Comment: what is `data`, is it `{data:{name:"",age:""}}` or `{name:"",age:""}`

Comment: it it is `{name:"",age:""}` then bind using `data="model"`

Comment: data is an array. {"data": [{"name": "", "age": ""}]}. Anyhow, I have narrowed the cause down to `$http.get()` statement. The data that it returns is directly assigned to `model` but it is causing some problems. File `everything.json` contains only the Object {..} nothing else. If I replace `$http.get()` with directly assigning the object to `model`, then my problem is solved.

Comment: can you share the `http.get()` function, is it happening in the main page controller/directive controller

Comment: It looks like a classic async processing problem, to debug the problem you can add some console statement like before the `http.get()` call, inside the `http.get()` success handler, and inside the directive controller and see the order of execution

Comment: the `$http.get()` is happening inside the Main Controller. Will take your suggestion and see the flow using `console.log()`

Comment: if you can share the directive we can look at what can be done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anytime something like `console.log($scope);` works, but `console.log($scope.someProperty);` doesn't, it is because `someProperty` is being set as a result of resolving a promise (such as an $http call or a promise created with $q).

The first log appears to work, when what is actually happening is that by the time you manually look at the log entry (i.e., click to expand its contents), the value has been populated/resolved.

In your controller, you'll need to $watch the property, and set up the watch callback function to do whatever it is you want to do with the data once it arrives/is resolved.